# How to use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow with AccessType is offline

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have to implement a function to upload a file to Google Drive.
As in [Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart) guide.

At first, I call generateLinkAuth to generate the link to get the code.
Then generateCode will be executed to get the token.
Everything is fine.

```
    List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    public String generateLinkAuth() {
            mHttpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            mJsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

            mFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(mHttpTransport, mJsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES).setAccessType("online").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();


            String url = mFlow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();

            System.out.println("url :" + url);
            return url;
        }

        public void generateCode(String code) {
            new GetCredentialFromCode(mContext, code).execute();
        }


        class GetCredentialFromCode extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            private Context mContext;
            private String code;
            private final ProgressDialog mDialog;

            public GetCredentialFromCode(Context context, String cd) {
                mContext = context;
                mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                mDialog.show();
                mDialog.setTitle("Uploading ...");
                code = cd;
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                if (mFlow != null) {
                    try {

                        mResponse = mFlow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();

                        mCredential = new GoogleCredential();

                        mCredential.setFromTokenResponse(mResponse);


                        String accessToken = mCredential.getAccessToken();
                        Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
                        edit.putString(GOOGLE_DRIVE_TOKEN, accessToken);
                        edit.commit();

                        String accessTokenSave = mPrefs.getString(GOOGLE_DRIVE_TOKEN, "NO KEY");
                        Log.e(TAG, "access Token Saved is " + accessTokenSave);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
                        edit.putString(GOOGLE_DRIVE_TOKEN, "NO KEY");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                String accessTokenSave = mPrefs.getString(GOOGLE_DRIVE_TOKEN, "NO KEY");

                mHttpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
                mJsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
                mCredential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessTokenSave);

                getUserInfo();

                mDriveService = new Drive.Builder(mHttpTransport, mJsonFactory, mCredential).build();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                GoogleDriveLogInAct act=  (GoogleDriveLogInAct) mContext;
                act.goBackSettingScreen();
            }

        }
```

The problem is that the token will expire in 1 hour with setAccessType("online"), so I change it to setAccessType("offline").
When I change it and run my android app again, I get an error - when I execute the below code.

```
                mResponse = mFlow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();

                mCredential = new GoogleCredential();

                mCredential.setFromTokenResponse(mResponse);
```

When I try to debug on console execute *mCredential.setFromTokenResponse(mResponse).* , an exception will be raised

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please use the Builder and call setJsonFactory, setTransport and setClientSecrets
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.setRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:294)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.setRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:153)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.setFromTokenResponse(Credential.java:556)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.setFromTokenResponse(GoogleCredential.java:313)
    at com.jp.shotdocs.libs.GoogleDriveLib$GetCredentialFromCode.doInBackground(GoogleDriveLib.java:168)
    at com.jp.shotdocs.libs.GoogleDriveLib$GetCredentialFromCode.doInBackground(GoogleDriveLib.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    ... 4 more
```

How can I use accessType offline?
Is there anything I have to modify to use with this mode?

Comment: I have solve this problem... I should declare GoogleCredential by using GoogleCredential.Build() instead of new GoogleCredential().

Comment: Please post an anser rather than a comment, otherwise the question remains in the unanswered section

Comment: To my understanding, please check whether i am right.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> have solve this problem... I should declare `GoogleCredential` by using `GoogleCredential.Build()` instead of `new GoogleCredential()`.